# What happens to woodbury matrix identity when A is not invertible?

Tags: matrices, inverse, matrix-decomposition, pseudoinverse

The Woodbury matrix identity is
\begin{equation}
(A+UCV)^{-1}=A^{-1}-A^{-1}U(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1}.
\end{equation}
This formula suppose that $A$, $(A+UCV)$ and $(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)$
are invertible. What happens to this formula when $A$ is not invertible
please? Do you know a formula for that case please? I have read the
paper " A Sherman Morrison Woodbury
Identity for Rank Augmenting Matrices with Application to Centering "
of Kurt S. Riedel but his formula looks so complicated. Thanks.